# Date on website

Tags: wordpress, date, datetime

I am building a website which will be viewed in UK, USA, and Europe, and want to know the best short date format to use.

I have been reading http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date which reads...

> *The international format defined by ISO (ISO 8601) tries to address all these problems by defining a numerical date system as follows:
>
> YYYY-MM-DD where YYYY is the year [all the digits, i.e. 2012]
>
> MM is the month [01 (January) to 12 (December)]
>
> DD is the day [01 to 31]
>
> For example, "3rd of April 2002", in this international format is written:
>
> 2002-04-03.*

...but still think that leaves room for error. The best I have seen is the [BBC website](http://www.bbc.co.uk/) uses "Thursday, 30 July" for example. Any suggestions?

Also, are there any Wordpress plugins that will handle this for me?

Comment: What do you mean by "leaves room for error?" ISO 8601 is the ultimate in unambiguous, full-featured date formats. It's meant as a way to communicate dates for automated systems. Are you asking about how to represent a date for users to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive used this plugin before https://wordpress.org/plugins/date-and-time-widget/screenshots/ which worked well (site is down now).

I agree with Zdeněk Šimůnek that you don't need the year. This plugin caters for all outputs really well.

If you want to manually add it with php, this is a good tutorial http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-finding-current-date-time-in-php/.

Answer (score 1):

The BBC style is by me the best. If you were to write the month in number you would come to situation, where viewers in Europe would think that its for example 1st of February and in USA 2nd of January. Year is not needed as almost everybody knows what year it is. The day of the week is optional.
PS.: Many sites also writes a name day for current datum.